# General pathfinder in Python

Tags: python, object-oriented

I was recently working on a project where I had the following setup:

```
from stargaze.sg import SGObject
from stargaze.constants import NegInf, Infinite, PATH_CLAMPED, PATH_REVERSIBLE, PATH_ACCELERATABLE
from stargaze.utils import clamp

__all__ = [
    'PathIdentifier', '_basePath', '_clampedPath', '_reversiblePath', 
    '_acceleratablePath', 'Path'
    ]

class PathIdentifier(SGObject):
    """
    INTERNATL: The base identifier class for a class object.
    """
    OBJ_REPR_PREFIX = "StarGaze Path:: "

class _basePath(PathIdentifier):
    def __init__(self, **config):
        self._time = 0
        self.speed = config['speed']

    def __move__(self):
        self._time += self.speed

class _clampedPath(PathIdentifier):

    def __init__(self, **config):
        start = config['start']
        end = config['end']
        if start > end:
            errmsg = "Start point cannot be greater " \
                     "than the end point."
            raise ValueError(errmsg)
        self._time = start
        self.end = end

        self.finished = False

    def __move__(self):
        if self.finished:
            return

        if self._time >= self.end:
            self.finished = True

class _reversiblePath(PathIdentifier):

    def __init__(self, **config):
        self.direction = 1

    def __move__(self):
        if self.direction == 1 and self._time >= 1:
            self.direction = -1
            self.speed *= -1
        elif self.direction == -1 and self._time <= 0:
            self.direction = 1
            self.speed *= -1

class _acceleratablePath(PathIdentifier):


    def __init__(self, speed, acceleration, min_speed=NegInf, max_speed=Infinite):
    def __init__(self, **config):
        self.accel = config['acceleration']

        self.min_speed = config.get('min_speed', NegInf)
        self.max_speed = config.get('max_speed', Infinite)

    def __move__(self):
        if self.accel != 1:
            self.speed = clamp(self.accel * self.speed, 
                self.max_speed, 
                self.min_speed)

class Path:

    def __init__(self, flags, **config):
        _basePath.__init__(self, **config)
        if flags & PATH_CLAMPED:
            _clampedPath.__init__(self, **config)
        if flags & PATH_REVERSED:
            _reversiblePath.__init__(self, **config)
        if flags & PATH_ACCELERATABLE:
            _acceleratablePath.__init__(self, **config)

        self.flags = flags

    def move(self):
        flags = self.flags

        if flags & PATH_CLAMPED:
            _clampedPath.__move__(self)

        if flags & PATH_REVERSED:
            _reversiblePath.__move__(self)

        if flags & PATH_ACCELERATABLE:
            _acceleratablePath.__move__(self)
```

None of the code is relevant, you won't have to be able to run any of it to answer my question. What I do in this code essentially is I create classes that define their own `__init__` and `__move_` methods, but I don't call them from instances of their class. Instead, I call them as class methods acting on the instance of another class. Is this bad style in Python? How else might I achieve what I was trying to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using classes as function containers. `Path` doesn't inherit from any of the other classes, yet you are passing your self instance to their initializer functions.

```
class _basePath:
    def __init__(self, **config):
        #Initialize Here
class Path:
    def __init__(self, flags, **config):
        _basePath.__init__(self, **config)
```

is no different from

```
def _base_path_init(instance, flag **config):
        #Initialize Here
class Path:
    def __init__(self, flags, **config):
        _base_path_init(self, **config)
```

You do the same thing in `move()` to access the specific move implementations.

If you take a step back, this code looks like it is trying to combine the concept of an object model with the concept of mixins or traits. Instead, if we take a step back and focus on the object model concept, the code can be simplified.

```
class Path(SGObject):
  def __init__(self, flags, **configs):
    SGObject.__init__(self)
    self._traits = []
    if flags & PATH_CLAMPED:
        self._traits.append(ClampedPath(self, **config))
    if flags & PATH_REVERSED:
        self._traits.append(ReversiblePath(self, **config))
    if flags & PATH_ACCELERATABLE:
        self._traits.append(AcceleratablePath(self, **config))

  def move(self):
    for trait in self._traits:
      trait.move(self)
```

Then each model would have the following interface.

```
class PathTrait(object):
  def __init__(self, instance, **configs):
     #Initialize Instance Here
  def move(instance):
     #Alter Instance Here
```

**Notes**:

The above assumes that the order of move operations needs to be enforced by `Path` (ie. `ClampedPath`'s move must occur before `ReversiblePath`'s move). If this is not the case, the initializer can be simplified to just take a list of model classes.

```
class Path(SGObject):
  def __init__(self, traits, **configs):
    SGObject.__init__(self)
    self._traits = [t(self, **config) for t in traits]
```

This allows you more flexibility in the future and removes the needs for flags entirely.

---

The way to code is written now, `_clampedPath` introduces the concept of movement no longer being allowed. If the path is clamped and it has finished, should the other traits execute at all?

Answer (score 2):

This certainly seems like an odd structure for the code; I've never seen anything implemented like this. I would suggest either:

1. If you need to have those classes stand-alone (e.g. you also create a `_clampedPath()` instance directly) you could make them inherited super-classes; or
2. If you don't, move all of the logic inside `Path`.

It is not clear which of these cases applies; Python convention is for a leading underscore to indicate "don't use this directly", but then you specifically include those classes in `__all__`.

The former would mean that the `Path` methods became:

```
class Path(ClampedPath, ReversiblePath, AcceleratablePath):

    def __init__(self, flags, **config):
        super().__init__(self, flags, **config)
```

The `flags` checking would then be moved to the corresponding methods in the super-classes, e.g.

```
class AcceleratablePath(BasePath):

    def __init__(self, flags, **config):
        super().__init__(self, flags, **config)
        if flags & PATH_ACCELERATABLE:
            self.accel = config['acceleration']
            self.min_speed = config.get('min_speed', NegInf)
            self.max_speed = config.get('max_speed', Infinite)
```

In the latter, rather than cram everything into long methods (which may have been why you did this in the first place), split it out like:

```
class Path(SGObject):

    OBJ_REPR_PREFIX = "StarGaze Path:: "

    def __init__(self, flags, **config):
        super()
        self._time = 0
        self.speed = config['speed']
        if flags & PATH_ACCELERATABLE:
            self._init_accel(flags, **config)
        ...

    def _init_accel(self, flags, **config):
        self.accel = config['acceleration']
        self.min_speed = config.get('min_speed', NegInf)
        self.max_speed = config.get('max_speed', Infinite)
```

Also, in terms of following Python conventions, the method name format `__foo__` is reserved for [special method names](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names); you should call your method(s) `move`. Per [PEP-0008](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) (emphasis mine):

> `__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__`: "magic" objects or attributes that live in user-controlled namespaces. E.g. `__init__`, `__import__` or `__file__`. **Never invent such names; only use them as documented**.